# How to delete a specific row in a 28GB delimited text file?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to delete row 10,754,960 in my very large delimited text file.  Ideally I'd like to see what text is on this row - SQL server import is telling me there is an error (I believe some data cleansing is needed).

Worst case, I just want to get rid of it.

Any idea using programming or some software package?  The text file is too large to open up itself on my laptop.

Comment: Why are you tagging with SQL server **and** mysql?

Comment: Do you know the row number?

Comment: Because the error initially appeared when trying to import via SQL server.  The row number is 10,754,960.

Comment: What OS? Also, it is not too large to open up on your *laptop*, it might be too large to open up with the specific *software* you're using. `vim` should happily open up any size of file as long as you're not using syntax highlighting (also see [LargeFile](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LargeFile) plugin that disables some of the slowdown features).

Comment: If he's on SQL server, he's on windows, if he's using MySQL, he could be anywhere @Amadan

Comment: Windows 7, MS SQL Server.

Comment: Is the text file in SQL or not? If not just the TAIL and HEAD tools from CYGWIN. It should be fairly simple

Comment: Is there a solution with UltraEdit or some other kind of text editor?

Comment: Text file is not in SQL.  Just a flat file.

Comment: If you're using UltraEdit, according to the authors you should not have too many problems. See [this](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html) page for hints (obviously, do not disable line numbers, even if it will slow you down). But @mti2935's answer is also very good: Unix tools are very, very powerful.

Comment: Is it a comma separated file ? Are you using SQL Server ? HAve you tried Open query http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5869d247-f0a0-4224-80b3-ff2e414be402/how-to-read-csv-file-in-sql-server-2005-using-openrowset-function ?

Comment: UltraEdit is able to load huge files, i used it myself to edit such files. From a certain size (depending on the settings) it will not load the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

sed is the tool for the job.

If your are on a Linux box, the following sed command will do the trick:
sed -i 10754960d /your/text/file.txt

If you are on a Windows box, you can get a version of sed for Windows from Sourceforge at the link below, then use the command above:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Answer (score 0):

Why not feed the file into an SSIS import package?
You could then wrap a DataViewer output around the import, so you can retrieve what information you require about the failed data?

Or you can try [error descriptions](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/1969.aspx)

- First Create an Import Data task using SSMS
- Save the package to your filesystem and then edit it in Business Intelligence Studio
- Follow instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms140318.aspx) to add a data viewer in between the Source and Data Conversion

Comment: Thanks.  Could you elaborate a bit more on how to explicitly do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of C# code that will allow you to do this from code. This basically creates new file by reading existing one but skips the line that has errors.

```
private const string OLD_FILE = @"C:\file1.csv";
private const string NEW_FILE = @"C:\file2.csv";

private void RemoveLine()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(OLD_FILE);
    StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(NEW_FILE);

    int counter = 1;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (counter != 10754960)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
        counter++;
    }
    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();

}
```